# Generating a control in Manipulate depending on the value of another control

Tags: manipulate

I would like to dynamically generate a checkbox in Manipulate depending on the actual value (True or False) of another checkbox. How could this easily be achieved?
Many thanks.

Comment: [interdependent \[tag:Manipulate\]](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interdependent%20%5bManipulate%5d) pick one

Comment: Thank you very much. Enabled->check1==True grays it out. And I'll try out the other possibilities.